# Running multiple apps in a server hiding ports

Tags: apache, redirect, https, port, rasa

Im developing two different chatbots and I have them on a Google Platform VM. I want to know how to access to them like this:

-> https://example.com/chatbot1

-> https://example.com/chatbot2

Instead of having:

-> https://example.com:5001

-> https://example.com:5002

I want to do that so I can run multiple chatbots on the same VM and I dont expose the ports. After doing this the idea is to insert the chatbot on a 3rd user web like this:

```
<script>
  WebChat.default.init({
    selector: "#webchat",
    initPayload: "XXX",
    interval: 1000,
    customData: {"userId": "123"},
    socketUrl: "http://example.com/chatbot1",
    socketPath: "/socket.io/",
    title: "XXX",
    subtitle: "XXX",
    inputTextFieldHint: "XXX",
    connectingText: "XXX",
    hideWhenNotConnected: true,
    fullScreenMode: false,
    showFullScreenButton: false,
    profileAvatar: "xxx.jpg",
    params: {
      images: {
        dims: {
          width: 250,
          height: 200,
        }
      },
      storage: "XXX",
    },
  })
</script>
```

Both need to run through HTTPS. Do I need Apache or something similar? If this is the case, how can I configure it? I dont know if it is relevant but I only have access to the VM through SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to use Apache's [name-based virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#page-header) (see the example under `Running different sites on different ports`).